# Custom meta fields and meta keys

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I read that you should only use lowercase letters for meta keys for custom fields - is this true? I need to set up several custom meta fields for products, and I would like to use a capitalized first letter for the keys.

Comment: Its not a rule, that you only need to use lowercase letters, nothing bad will happen. Its good practice to use lowercase letters for meta. But what is the reason for capitalized first letter?

Comment: Are you hoping to have two separate values, one with and one without? In my install the values are collated case insensitively, so they're the same value. Or are you intending to display the keys directly to users? You could use some other way to map these; I'd worry about filtering down to only the set I wanted to show.

Comment: @Rup and  I need the label to be displayed before the value, and if I set a different meta key name (different from the label that should be displayed) I would have to write code specifically for each custom field (10 fields in total) ... is it also still possible to filter by these fields when they have a capitalized letter?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use lower-case keys (as is best practice) and [capitalize them on output](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)?

Comment: @vancoder I thought about this like    echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', array_map("ucfirst", $custom_data ));
   but I also have one meta key name that would need a str replace (from product_number to Product-Number) and not sure how to do this...